# run vba script for cells in column after specific row

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code so when a user clicks on AQ in a column, the subsequent cell AS in that row is updated with the date.

However i am trying to get this to only work on those cells which are in row 8 or higher, so in other words i dont want rows 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 affected.

Is there a way i can say if row is 8 of higher? or 8-37?

also is there a way to only run this code when cell AQ = certain text? else otherwise do nothing?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = Range("AQ8").Column Then
    Range("AS" & Target.Row).Value = "=TODAY()"
  End If
End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe `Target.Row`? And `Target.Value` for contents. And logical operators `And, Or` to glue everything in one condition.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row > 8 And Target.Column = 43 And Target.Value = "Send Email" Then
       Target(1, 2).Value = Date()
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Nested in the worksheet module.

Comment: hi thanks for this what does if target.column = 43 mean? is this the code that says run code if the cell contains 43?

Comment: No, it says to go to column AQ. Q = 17th letter, AQ = 26+17 = 43

Comment: ok thanks, any idea how i could only get this code to run if the AQ cell in a row = Send Email as a value?